"to do social media-ing". --- Is it really used like this in daily life?
A teacher is telling about how boring text books may be in learning language and how students behave usually. She says:
"And then you close the book and you forget it, or like, "Oh, my phone, let me do some social media-ing here." Play games in improve English (see: 1:38-1:45)
"to do social media-ing" sounds interesting to me. Never heard it being used like this. I checked the subtitles. This is exactly how it is written, with a hypen (media-ing).
Does she use it to mean more than simply looking at social media. I mean not just looking at what is new there, but also sharing things, putting content on there, editing things, trying to get more followers, etc" on social media?

Incorrectly using a noun as a verb is sometimes done for comedic effect, especially to lightly mock or degrade someone. "Take a break from Call of Duty-ing and clean your room." "John was supposed to be here too, but he's too busy girlfriend-ing."

Using a noun as a verb is common informally - see this question on "people" as a verb, and google "adulting".

This is not standard English. It is very informal.
In general, we have separate words for the verb and the noun in an activity. Like we say, "Al drove a car." We don't say "he carred". We say "Betty read a magazine", not "she magazined". Etc.
But sometimes we do just use the noun as a verb. Like if you ride a sled, we may say "You sledded". But frankly I can't think of many examples of that.
So in this case, I would have said, "Let me use social media", or perhaps something more specific, like, "I will post on social media."
As to exactly what it means ... that's the problem with inventing a word. Unless you carefully define it, readers aren't sure what you mean. Does she mean, "read social media"? "Make posts on social media"? "Search social media for specific information"? Etc. She may well just mean a very general, "use social media".

There's plenty of examples of noun-derived verbs meaning broadly "to use X", it's just that most of them end up just being accepted as part of the language (bicycling or hammering wouldn't make anyone bat an eye). Verbing weirds language, in the words of great philosopher Calvin.
